# Do I need to buy a flight ticket for my appealing to the german embassy

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, visa-refusals, proof-of-onward-travel

Good day everyone, I applied for a german visa and it was refused.  I want to write appeal later with other documents that will show that I will come back after my one month soccer program.  My question is do I need to buy a flight ticket attach the photo copy and send to them.

Comment: What was the reason for refusal?

Comment: Buying a flight ticket *before* being approved, and now after being refused, might not come across very well. Anyone can show they can buy a ticket.

Comment: Adding details of your nationality, your current status (student, full-time job, etc.), age, the type of visa requested, the reason for the refusal, all the documentation you provided the first time, what exactly your "one month soccer program" is, and any other relevant information would be useful to people trying to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The Schengen visa rules are supposed to let genuine tourists in and to keep unregulated economic migrants out. You have to convince them that you are not an economic migrant.

- Can you reasonably afford the vacation? That means you have to have enough money, and you have to have enough *income* to make spending that much money credible.
- Do you appear likely to return to your homeland? It would be helpful if you have a stable job situation, family ties, real estate, etc.

And a specific German note: **Who organizes your soccer program?** If the DFB is involved, they might be able to help.

Comment: Good morning everyone, There reasons for my visa refusal #3. You have provided proof of sufficient means of substance, for the duration of the intended stay or for return to the country of origin or residence, or for the transit to a third country into which you are certain to be admitted, or you are not in a position to acquire such means lawfully.